# Can pipenv CLI be used to install into dev-packages with --keep-outdated option?

Tags: python, pipenv

I want to install a package with pipenv into the `dev-packages` list with pipenv without floating the version of the other packages.  I know I can just add the package under the `[dev-packages]` heading, but I want to install from the command line so that I can use the `--keep-outdated` option.

For example say my `Pipfile` looks like this:

```
[dev-packages]
black = "*"

[packages]
boto = "*"
```

I want to install `ipython` into the dev packages list without upgrading `boto`.  The real `Pipfile` is much more complicated with many unpinned packages I don't want to float the version on.  It would be awesome if I could do `pipenv install -d ipython --keep-outdated` from the commandline, but I can't find anything about how to do that.

Comment: What prevents you to use this command? It looks fine.

Comment: @Swar - wow, I feel dumb.  I had tried it and got an error so I had it in mind that it didn't work.  After retrying the command in the question does in fact work.  Thanks!